# How to get the most out of the raspberry pi 2 GPU?

Tags: streaming-video, gpu, pi-2

I just purchased the raspberry pi 2 and I was trying to use it to make my "non-smart" TV a bit smarter. Basically, instead of connecting my laptop (via HDMI) to the TV every time I wanted to watch online movies on a bigger screen, I thought to leave the Pi 2 always behind the TV for this purpose.

I tried different OSs, first the raspian from NOOBS, then Ubuntu (from https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi). However I always found very slow frame rate when watching. On the other hand I see very good review about the Pi GPU. So, is the Pi 2 just not mean to be used this way or I'm missing some config?

Comment: Right now, this is kind of a rhetorical question.  If you can clarify what you mean by "watch online movies" and "very slow frame rate", then you might have something that can be specifically answered.

Comment: @goldilocks Sorry. It seemed self explanatory. I meant warching movies or simply a video via the www on any browser. E.g. youtube or amazon prime movie. And slow frame rate I mean it seems more of a sequence of images than a video

Comment: Okay, but what's the problem in detail?  *Frame rate* refers to the speed at which something was recorded and (hopefully) plays back.  So are you saying that the video is in slow motion?  That it stutters a lot?

Comment: Yes exactly, on the Pi 2 it stutters a lot. I watched the same video on my laptop and it is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a browser, there probably is no GPU hardware acceleration regardless of distro.

So, with regard to youtube, you might want to try [youtube-dl](http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/) to download them and then use `omxplayer` -- which was written for the pi's GPU -- to watch them.  It's pre-installed in Raspbian but may not be available in Snappy Core Ubuntu.

Omxplayer uses the framebuffer outside of the GUI desktop; I'm not sure if it can be run from the GUI, but you should be able to find a free console via Ctrl-Alt-F1-6 (just try the F-keys in order, when you get to a console log in).  Then:

```
omxplayer -o hdmi whatever.mp4
```

This will give you an idea of optimally what you should get.  I don't use the pi for video that much, but using this method (downloading first, then watching via `oxmplayer`) fullscreen, HD quality stuff has been fine.

Omxplayer can also [play internet streams directly](http://elinux.org/Omxplayer), so you should be able to then check if the problem is related to that.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. So, if I understand correctly you can't benefit from the hardware accelaration for any video not stored in the micro SD, right?

Comment: No, you can (see last paragraph), I'm just recommending you test it without downloading at the same time since that's optimal.  What you probably can't get is hardware acceleration via a browser plugin.

Comment: Ok. Thanks again. The last part (about the browser plugin) explains a lot, very helpful.

Comment: I am getting following error: "* failed to open vchiq instance"

Comment: @Trismegistos Sounds like you should ask a separate question explaining *in appropriate detail* exactly what it is you want to do, exactly how you are trying to do it, and exactly what happens instead of what you want.

Answer (score -1):

I know it's probably a bit past prime for this answer but I thought I'd chime in.  I just stumbled across a neat little package called openelec.tv.  It's a linux wrapper for Kodi (aka XBMC).  There's a raspberry pi distribution and it takes full advantage of all the hardware acceleration on the Pi 2.  Check it out!